# Keep as numpy array type when returning a scalar

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types, scalar

An array `a = np.array(1)` is convenient as it allows `a.shape` **

How can I preserved the `numpy` class type when doing an operation that returns a scalar e.g.

```
b = 0.

c = np.dot(a.T, a)

b+=c

b.shape
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-82ed078d10e8> in <module>()
----> 1 b.shape

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

** really useful when doing dimensionality checks during complex operations that should be returning scalars (e.g. multi-index tensor summation)

Comment: I just noticed my issue... ugh. I'll leave this up though as it's not that trivial and there's no similar question. The solution is setting `b = np.array(0)` initially. By setting `b=0.` the operation `b+=0` casts the `c` back into a float.

Comment: Usually, instead of a 0-dimensional array, you want a NumPy array scalar. Those have a `shape` like arrays, but they behave a bit more like scalars in a few ways (such as immutability). There's also `numpy.shape`. Whatever you choose, 0-dimensional objects have a bunch of annoying edge cases that make them a lot more awkward to work with than higher-dimensional data.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm working in 40^4~2.5million dimensions so I am very interested in *annoying edge cases* - can you be more specific

Comment: Edge cases like [this thing](http://ideone.com/z8Byow), where 0-dimensional arrays follow different casting rules from 1-dimensional arrays, or [this thing](http://ideone.com/L3I6Db), where doing math with a 0-dimensional array produces a scalar instead of an array, or [this thing](http://ideone.com/vvenbq), where the rules for whether you get a scalar or an array when indexing a 0-dimensional object are really confusing.

Comment: www how annoying... thanks for the detailed effort you put in. I think that's worthy of an answer as you went to all that effort to host the examples